# how to know which user is dumping mysql database

Tags: mysql, database

I have some confidential database in MySQL. I want to restrict user to dump database and I want to know, which user has dumped the database. I didn't get any way to know about this. I tried with general logs, but I didn't find anything in MySQL.

Please let me know is there any way to get info about this .

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux server then you can block any command for users to take `mysqldump`. Find below procedure to block a command or to check `mysql/bash history`.

**-Check mysql/bash history.**

Goto home directory of user e.g. /home/user. In this directory you will find two files named `.mysql_history` and `.bash_history`. All command have stored in these files.

**-Block a command**

1- Try to find mysqldump command path

```
root@localhost:[~]: which mysqldump
/usr/bin/mysqldump
root@localhost:[~]:
```

As in above `mysqldump` command exist here `/usr/bin/mysqldump`

2- Remove command access from all other user except root

```
root@localhost:[~]: cd /usr/bin/
root@localhost:[/usr/bin]: chmod g-rwx mysqldump
root@localhost:[/usr/bin]: chmod o-rwx mysqldump
```

Above command will remove `mysqldump` command access to group and all other users except root.

Comment: @user2916639 May be but I don't now till now. You can try grep command to search all `mysqldump` command in `.bash_history` file.